# Delete all row based on condition in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to delete rows based on condition. Let me explain in detail,

table1

```
 -----------------
| t1id | t1detail |
|---------------  |
|  1   |  iii     |
|  2   |  jjj     |
|  3   |  iik     |
|  4   |  jjk     |
 -----------------
```

table2

```
 ------------------------
| t2id | t1id | t1detail |
|----------------------- |
|  1   |   1  | iii      |
|  2   |   1  | jja      |
|  3   |   3  | iib      |
|  4   |   1  | jjc      |
|  5   |   2  | iid      |
|  6   |   3  | jje      |
|  7   |   4  | iif      |
|  8   |   2  | jjg      |
|  9   |   3  | iih      |
|  10  |   4  | jj3      |
 ------------------------
```

Now I need to delete table1 id(t1id) at the same time in table2 all id assigned from tablet1 should be deleted.

for example, Suppose I need to delete t1id = 1 mean, it should delete from table1 and table2

in table1

```
 1   |  iii
```

in table2

```
1   |   1  | iii
2   |   1  | jja
4   |   1  | jjc
```

should be deleted. Kindly advice me to do in mysql

I tried with

```
    $query = "DELETE FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.t1id = table2.t1id  WHERE  table1.t1id = {$id};
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
```

but not successfull

Comment: One way would be to use foreign key constraints between the two tables, with "cascade on delete".  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: @mable :  Could you please share the exact query for my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you don't have foreign keys setup (maybe using MyISAM storage?). If that's the case you will need to specify both tables to delete from in your query.

```
DELETE table1, table2
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.t1id = table2.t1id
WHERE table1.t1id = {$id}
```

If you had foreign keys setup you could use cascading delete, which would solve your issue as well.

Comment: Agree with Brian. How about a stored Procedure for this?

Comment: @mable I don't think you're right on this one. Both the DELETE reference page and the JOIN reference page indicated that you can use JOINS in a DELETE statement.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll that's what I get for skimming ;)